# Tkinter tkFileDialog.askdirectory - returning directory above the one I want

Tags: python, tkinter

In Python, using Tkinter, I'm trying to use `tkFileDialog.askdirectory` to get the users selection of a directory.
It works - in so much as the dialog screen shows up OK, and there is a list of directory names to choose from.
I can then double click on a directory name and go down several levels.
When I get to the directory name I want - I click on it once, then click the OK button.

Now, it returns the name of the directory I was in, not the one I selected!
That is, for a directory tree like this:

> /home/user/log/messages/file_1

I can go down through `/home` then `user` then `log` and single click on the directory called `messages`, then click OK button.

The returned string is `"/home/user/log"`

But, what I want is `"/home/user/log/messages"`.

Why does it do that? it's not what I would expect.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root, initialdir="/", title='Please select a directory')
if len(dirname ) > 0:
    print "You chose %s" % dirname
```

I'm using Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: please show a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem.

Comment: `import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
 
 root = Tkinter.Tk() 
 dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please select a directory')
 if len(dirname ) > 0:
     print "You chose %s" % dirname`

Comment: Sorry about the above MCVE. the `code` doesn't seem to work on here. It's lost all the newlines and stuff, and condensed it all as one line.

Comment: @Nick That's because you posted it in a comment. Instead, you should edit it into your question. I've now done it for you.

Comment: Also, why is your question tagged with `python-3.x`? The use of Tkinter with a capital suggests you are actually using Python 2.x. It would probably make more sense to simply use the `python` tag anyway, since I doubt this problem has anything to do with the python version. Instead, it would be useful if you explicitly included (not as a tag, just in the question) your OS, since `askdirectory` is a native file dialog on windows and OSX, but is implemented in python on linux. So the behavior is very OS dependent. On Windows 7 for example, I can not replicate this behavior.

Comment: Hi guys, apologies for my inexperience with using SO, and the many breaches of etiquette etc. I don't know where the Python-3.x tag came from, I just typed Python!. I am using Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. If that helps.

Comment: @Nick I have no experience with or access to a machine with Ubuntu, so I'm afraid I won't be able to help you. I did edit the information into the question though, which bumps it up in the "Active questions" list, so i hope someone who can help you will see this question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question "Why does it do that?" is of course: "Because it was programmed that way." ;-)

In fact you have do **double** click the directory you want as well.
The return value is what you see at the bottom of the dialogue ("your selection" or similar - in Germany it says: "Auswahl").

-yes-